# How can I handle two different touch points at different positions at the exact same time in sprite kit's `touchesBegan:` method?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I've tried different ways to handle two touch handlers in different positions in `touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:` but it never worked for two touches at once, there was only one touch being handled every time I touched two different points at the same time. How can I achieve this? Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you try setting the view's `multipleTouchEnabled` property to `YES`?

Comment: oh, I'm gonna try that, Thanks so much for mentioning that!!!!! @rmaddy

Comment: Yes it worked, I was applying the `multipleTouchEnabled` to the parent view but i needed it in a subview in which i implemented my skscene, Thank you so much. @rmaddy